# Держать всегда RecycleView внизу списка

Tags: java, android, kotlin, recyclerview

У меня приложение на подобии чата, как сделать так что бы при создании он сам прокручивался вниз, я сделал, но при добавлении нового сообщения, и при вызове `notifyDataSetChanged()` он сам не прокручивается, даже если вызывать функции

```
recyclerView.onScrollStateChanged(adapter!!.messageList.lastIndex)
layoutManager?.onScrollStateChanged(adapter!!.itemCount - 1)
```

Ничего не меняется

код создания

```
 private fun initRecycleView() {
        val fragment = this
        GlobalScope.launch {
            val list = chatPresenter.loadMessages()
            adapter = ChatMessagesAdapter(list, fragment)
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                recyclerView.adapter = adapter
            }
        }
        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
        layoutManager?.stackFromEnd = true
        recyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager
        recyclerView.hasFixedSize()

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать

```
LinearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true)
```

Или

```
LinearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true)
```

Это сделает ориентацию вашего RecyclerView снизу вверх. Таким образом вам не придется ваше никуда двигать ваш RecyclerView

Comment: А как его сделать снизу вверх